# Angular offline - cannot match any routes because of file path

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, adobe-illustrator

I'm using Angular in an Extension for Adobe Illustrator. Everything works fine, until testing on a Windows machine, where the Extension bundle is stored under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\CEP\extensions
```

The error looks like this:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'x86'
```

[image: Angular error]

So I don't understand why the 'x86' is the problem, and what I can do about it...

Best regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but instead of base href="./", I had to define this in index.html:

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```